# Помогите разобраться как включить регистр накопления в 1С

Tags: 1с

Я занимаюсь изучением 1С: Предприятие 8.3 Практическое пособие разработчика. Возникла проблема: я пытаюсь сделать регистр накопления «Остатки материалов», который будет использоваться в трех подсистемах «Бухгалтерия», «ОказаниеУслуг» и «УчетМатериалов». Сам регистр я уже настроил, конструктор движений тоже. Но в командном интерфейсе просто нету позиции регистра, которую по идее я должен включить и убрать из невидимости. Даже в составе документа видно, что регистр есть, но в самом командном интерфейсе его не видно, хотя по всем учебным пособиям он должен находиться там (подчеркнуто красным).

Подскажите, что делать и как это вообще работает. Могу докинуть еще какие либо скрины, если это поможет с решением проблемы.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Он же регистр, зачем ему там быть?

Comment: В учебнике написано, что он должен быть там и в пользовательском интерфейсе должен высвечиваться, но этого не происходит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

для регистра накопления включи в свойствах "Использовать стандартные команды"
https://monosnap.com/file/LcxAOLUBzPVs3fsfhX3piBwW0eygsr

*Если это решение Вам помогло, то не забудьте его отметить флажком, спасибо.*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Как поправить:

- Настройки на скрине: настройка самого командного интерфейса. Т.е. командный интерфейс настраивается исходя из состава подсистемы. Регистр же, как я понимаю, не включен в состав подсистемы. Можно в самой подсистеме открыть состав и отметить регистр, или же в объекте регистра зайти на вкладку «Подсистемы» и отметить нужную тебе подсистему

Для чего нужно:

- Ну, на самом деле подсистемами не сильно пользуюсь, но всё же: они больше нужны для автоматического разделения и расположения каких-то кусков конфигурации собственно в отдельных кусках-подсистемах. При этом не нужно будет рисовать формы с выбором каких-то команд или объектов - всё отрисует платформа. При этом вверху окна 1С появляются эти подсистемы, а при нажатии на них отображается их состав. Что-то типа подменю, если так удобней будет

Comment: Дело то в том, что вроде как регистр включен в состав подсистемы. Я все проверял и делал как написано в пособии и в гайдах, но все равно не работает. (2 скрин в посте)

Comment: Попробуй изменить командный интерфейс одной подсистемы, а не всех разом. Ну и почисти кэш заодно :)

Comment: Я и так изменяю командный интерфейс одной подсистемы.

Comment: Все равно ничего не помогает

Answer (score 0):

В пользовательском режиме нужно добавлять, если в конфигурации все включено.
В открытом окне документа нажать троеточие - Окно - Настройка панели навигации и добавить все нужные регистры